How to make a flexible argument list for cursor.execute in python3?
In fact, I want to increase and decrease the mysql query items and the values ​​(arguments) according to the status of the variable values.
based on my scenario I need to make a flexible mysql query individual with its arguments.
    connection = pymysql.connect(host="", user="", passwd="", db="")
    myquery = connection.cursor()

    insARGS = ""
    content_id = 1097
    page_title = "test page title"

    insQuery = 'UPDATE ex_content SET'
    insARGS = ""
    insARGSdictionary = {}

    if (len(page_title) > 0):
        print("page_title: "+page_title)
        print(type(page_title))
        pageTitleQuery = " c_title=%s"
        insQuery = insQuery + pageTitleQuery
        insARGS = "page_title"
        insARGSdictionary['page_title'] = page_title
    else:
        print("page_title is not bigger than 0")

    if (len(page_desc) > 0):
        print("page_desc: "+page_desc)
        pageDescQuery = ", c_meta_desc=%s"
        insQuery = insQuery + pageDescQuery
        insARGS = insARGS + ", page_desc"
        insARGSdictionary['page_desc'] = page_desc
    else:
        print("page_desc is not bigger than 0")
    if (len(page_heading) > 0):
        page_heading = ""
        print("page_heading: "+page_heading)
        pageHeadingQuery = ", c_heading=%s"
        insQuery = insQuery + pageHeadingQuery
        insARGS = insARGS + ", page_heading"
        insARGSdictionary['page_heading'] = page_heading
    else:
        print("page_heading is not bigger than 0")
    if (len(page_link) > 0):
        print("page_link: "+page_link)
        pageLinkQuery = ", c_link=%s"
        insQuery = insQuery + pageLinkQuery
        insARGS = insARGS + ", page_link"
        insARGSdictionary['page_link'] = page_link
    else:
        print("page_link is not bigger than 0")
    
    if content_id:
        print("content_id: "+str(content_id))
        contentIdQuery = ' WHERE c_id=%s '
        insQuery = insQuery + contentIdQuery
        insARGS = insARGS + ", content_id"
        insARGSdictionary['content_id'] = content_id

        list_of_dict_keys = list(insARGSdictionary.keys())
        queryArguments = (', '.join(map(str, list_of_dict_keys)))
        myquery.execute(insQuery, (queryArguments))


Also my data types in queryArguments may be vary (e.g. int or str or etc).
Thank you in advance for the advice

the second argument to myquery.execute() should be the values, not the keys. You don't even need a dictionary, use a list that you append to as you add to the query.
connection = pymysql.connect(host="", user="", passwd="", db="")
myquery = connection.cursor()

content_id = 1097
page_title = "test page title"

insQuery = 'UPDATE ex_content SET'
insARGSlist = []

if (len(page_title) > 0):
    print("page_title: "+page_title)
    print(type(page_title))
    pageTitleQuery = " c_title=%s"
    insQuery = insQuery + pageTitleQuery
    insARGSlist.append(page_title)
else:
    print("page_title is not bigger than 0")

if (len(page_desc) > 0):
    print("page_desc: "+page_desc)
    pageDescQuery = ", c_meta_desc=%s"
    insQuery = insQuery + pageDescQuery
    insARGSlist.append(page_desc)
else:
    print("page_desc is not bigger than 0")
if (len(page_heading) > 0):
    page_heading = ""
    print("page_heading: "+page_heading)
    pageHeadingQuery = ", c_heading=%s"
    insQuery = insQuery + pageHeadingQuery
    insARGSlist.append(page_heading)
else:
    print("page_heading is not bigger than 0")
if (len(page_link) > 0):
    print("page_link: "+page_link)
    pageLinkQuery = ", c_link=%s"
    insQuery = insQuery + pageLinkQuery
    insARGSlist.append(page_link)
else:
    print("page_link is not bigger than 0")

if content_id:
    print("content_id: "+str(content_id))
    contentIdQuery = ' WHERE c_id=%s '
    insQuery = insQuery + contentIdQuery
    insARGSlist.append(content_id)

    myquery.execute(insQuery, insARGSlist)


Dear @Barmar, It was Great, Thanks
